# Overriding drawRect: in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, drawrect

Why is it not recommended to override `drawRect`? I've read some people say in iOS7, they've changed the `UITableViewCell` engine and hence it's not recommended but I couldn't find any such recommendation in the Apple docs. I feel if it's a bad idea, Apple would mention it in their docs.

I ask because I was trying to draw a border on my custom cell subclass and noticed it draws on one kind of cell but not the other (code is identical). Note that this issue is only on iOS7 and only on the iPhone.

Comment: You can't just call `[super drawRect:]` in your override?

Comment: I did. it still didn't work. it works fine on ios6 (iPhone/ipad), and on an iPad running ios7.

Answer (score 2):

A `UITableViewCell` is comprised of many subviews. `drawRect:` should usually be used in a view with no subviews.

If anything, create a custom view with the desired `drawRect:` and then add an instance of that view to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it did work. I'm just trying to find out why it works on one kind of cell consistently and not on the other even though they have identical implementations.

Comment: We don't have enough info to know why you are seeing different behavior.